# how to sort this python code alphabetically

Tags: python, sorting, input, cpu-word, output

i've tried so hard to sort these code alphabetically but still not working. tis is the error message :

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Eclipse Workspace\tugas1\src\h.py", line 15, in 
    for word in set(l):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable**

here the code :

```
from re import compile

l=compile("(\w[\w']*)").findall(open(raw_input('Input file: '),'r').read().lower()).sort()

f=open(raw_input('Output file: '),'w')

for word in set(l):

    print>>f, word, ':', '\t', l.count(word), 'kata'

f.close()
```

Comment: *Sparse is better than dense*

Comment: Well who knows, he could have been following "Flat is better than nested." :)

Comment: @Shashank Having a few more lines doesn't make the code nested though.

Comment: @Voo True, good point.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `.sort()`. It sorts the list in place and returns `None`, so that is the result of the assignment. `l` is always `None.`. Do the sort separately, after all the other stuff.

```
l=compile("(\w[\w']*)").findall(open(raw_input('Input file: '),'r').read().lower())
l.sort()
```

Just BTW, there is no need to compile a regex if you're just going to use it once. No harm in doing so, though.

Comment: @kindall oke, now there's no error. but the word is still unsorted alphabetically. do you mind why?

Comment: Well, you're converting it a `set`, which does not maintain order, after you sort it. Maybe you want to do that the other way around?

Comment: @kindall i just want to sort alphabetically from text  and save the answer to an output file. can yo helo me please?

Comment: If you don't need a set, take out the `set()` call.

Answer (score 1):

`.sort()` sorts the list in place. It does not return the sorted list. Because it doesn't, it default to return `None`.

Thus, `l = None`. You don't want this.

Your code should be:

```
from re import compile
l = compile("(\w[\w']*)")
with open(raw_input('Input file: '),'r') as myfile:
    content = myfile.read().lower()
    l = l.findall(content)
    l.sort() # Notice how we don't assign it to anything

...
```

*Sparse is better than dense*. Don't try to put everything in one line

Comment: sorry, im new in python.
could you please repair my code? thx

Comment: @vynz5 Not without seeing the contents of the file you're trying to read

Comment: i do not see any change. the word is still unsorted (just the same as when i write a l.sort() like @kindall).

Comment: @vynz5 Before `l.sort()`, put `print l`. What appears?

Comment: just like you split your text into words

Comment: @vynz5 No, show me the output that appears when you run the script

Comment: ['jakarta', 'ikan', 'aligator', 'di', 'waduk', 'jatiluhur', 'berpotensi', 'membahayakan']

Comment: @vynz5 They should sort after `l.sort()`